# how to select distinct values in a column in entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My DB Table contains `ContractorName` as one of the columns. There are some other columns like `workinghoursforjoc`, `manpowerjoc`, `workinghoursforcontractor`, `manpowercontractor`. But, I want to retrieve the unique names of the contractor.

I tried in the following way.

```
var contractors = context.ManHoursWorked.Where(j => j.JOCID == jocID).Select(c => c.ContractorName).Distinct();
```

But I am getting the error

> Entity Command Execution Exception

Comment: The query looks good, please post the inner exception.

Comment: what is the type of the `ContractorName` column? varchar? text?

Comment: @FabioLuz It's type is nvarchar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add ToList() call at the end of the expression to materialize the query:

```
var contractors = context.ManHoursWorked.Where(j => j.JOCID == jocID).Select(c => c.ContractorName).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: And why would this help?

Comment: Strictly speaking I didn't checked what type of exception one can get if he would write the next line   contractors.Select(c => c.ToCharArray());  Perhaps, the EntityCommandExecutionException is rather about mapping errors.

Comment: @brainboost I had used the above query initially. I got the same error. Then I changed the query as in the question. Still it had shown me the same error

Comment: So, strictly speaking, this is not an answer.

Comment: @PSriharsha, if the problem remains could you show us your entity and mappings? One does not simply guess the problem.

Comment: @brainboost The problem was with datatype. I made the datatype as string. We have been using Oracle SQL developer. It has taken the type as nclob. I changed that to string. Problem was solved.